# Where exactly are my package units?

Tags: delphi, package, delphi-xe

I use packages, I even create them, but I'm afraid I've never understood them. I recently installed JCL and JVCL (great packages by the way!). Put some controls on a form. Everything allright. The same form is also used in my testing application. And there the compiler asks where the jedi units are: e.g. JvExControls. Uptill now I solved this problem by adding the units to my project, but that is not feasible for the Jedi files.

It seems to be a path problem, but as far I can see Jedi set the paths Ok. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JVCL installer normally does this for you. You could have something weird in your computer environment that prevented the installer from doing it, or you might have messed it up, after the install. You tried the usual first thing to try, I hope, which is just re-run the Jedi JCL and then the JVCL installers? (The JVCL depends on the JCL, so it is possible that the units that you are looking for are part of the JCL, not the JVCL. )

So there are BPL files, and those are in a folder that must be located in the system's `PATH` environment-variable, so they can be located by the RAD Studio IDE.

Secondly, there are PAS files, and those are usually found by going through the directories in your global `library path` - the installer usually sets that up for you and in Jedi's case it usually points at the DCU files instead of the PAS files -- if you didn't mess up your library path since the installer ran, then it *should* contain the paths of all the delphi units, including the Jedi JVCL ones, and other component vendor's folders.

Thirdly, some developers choose to set up their Project `Search Path` option in the Project Options, for each and every individual project file they have, so that Delphi can find things.

You should not only check all three things (`PATH` environment variable if the IDE can't load the packages when it starts up, and the others, if your code won't build), you should also look for duplicates or extra copies.

Instead of adding units to your project, try just using your Project `Search Path` option.

**Update** It might be because you're explicitly recompiling jvcl/jcl units by adding them to your projects, and because you have (therefore) got Jedi JVCL DCU files also, all over the place outside the jedi Library Dcu folders, that you have a mess.  Your solution is to build it all from source each time, which is a bit slower, but has the benefit of working for you, so that's okay.

Comment: thanks for your thorough remarks. I installed JCL first, next JVCL. There are .BPL's and they are in the `PATH`. There are *no* .PAS files in the `library path`, there are .DCU's. Does that explain the errors? Jedi set the `search path` for the Jedi files to the same directories as the `library path`.

Comment: Indeed it was the `library path` to the .PAS files. I added that and it worked. Thanks! What I don't understand is that in the project in which I added the Jedi components this causes no problems, but in another project, using the same files and paths, it does. I also don't understand why a path to the DCU's is necessary when I set a path to the .PAS files.

Comment: Normally the .DCUs should work for you and they are normally what should be in the library path. They should be functioning as pre-built DCUs. However if you explicitly including one JVCL or JCL unit as a .PAS file, then you may be forced to include ALL of them that way, thus your solution.

Comment: I'll experiment with the best setup. Thanks for your explanation, it helped me understanding packages better.